# How to css customize symfony form errors with bootstrap and twig?

Tags: symfony, bootstrap-4, twig, symfony4

For symfony form and twig I use

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}
```

with `bootstrap_4_horizontal_layout.html.twig`, it works fine and output is like:

```
<span class="alert alert-danger d-block"><span class="d-block">
                    <span class="form-error-icon badge badge-danger text-uppercase">Error</span> <span class="form-error-message">Error</span>
                </span></span>
```

But I need to customize it to translate that bootstrap ERROR label next to the message. Where I can customize it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can and probably should write your own form theme and override the `form_errors` block to adapt it to your needs. as reference: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/537d373e0d8cb11fa70ddbe9559f2c4a741117a9/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig#L294

so to implement your own form theme you just have to have a file, let's say `my_form_style.html.twig`:

```
{% extends "bootstrap_4_horizontal_layout.html.twig" %}

{# override the blocks you want ... or add some, this is the original #}
{%- block form_errors -%}
    {%- if errors|length > 0 -%}
        <span class="{% if form is not rootform %}invalid-feedback{% else %}alert alert-danger{% endif %} d-block">
            {%- for error in errors -%}
                <span class="d-block">
                    <span class="form-error-icon badge badge-danger text-uppercase">{{ 'Error'|trans({}, 'validators') }}</span> <span class="form-error-message">{{ error.message }}</span>
                </span>
            {%- endfor -%}
        </span>
    {%- endif %}
{%- endblock form_errors %}
```

and afterwards you just set the form theme to yours:

```
{% form_theme form "my_form_style.html.twig" %}
```

enjoy

Comment: As in `bootstrap_4_horizontal_layout.html.twig` there is no `form_errors` block, where is this current form error block coming from? @Jakumi

Comment: it's from `bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig`, which `bootstrap_4_horizontal_layout.html.twig` extends, which would be extended by your new form theme.

Comment: I see this layout has `{{ 'Error'|trans({}, 'validators') }}` too. I added 'ERROR' as array element in my translator catalog, it is still not translated. Any other errors are translated except this one and csrf invalid error. How to translate them too as I have them in my catalog? @Jakumi

Comment: `validators` is the name of the catalogue, which you can obviously change to your liking.

Comment: my current catalog name is `validators.fr.php` and it is working fine for all form errors except `ERROR` label and csrf. Do you mean those two are looking for another catalog name to find? @Jakumi

Comment: oh, you always have to translate what actually is in the template, so that would be `'Error'` (since that is what `|trans` is applied to), and not `'ERROR'`. the uppercasing is a result of the `text-uppercase` class, that turns the content of the `<span>` into uppercase (bootstrap). translation is obviously case-sensitive ;o)

Comment: Actually I tried 'Error' in my catalog too. Not translated! @Jakumi

Comment: cleared the cache? regarding a fix for the actual problem, I'm out of ideas. however, maybe you could just use a different catalogue, when you modify the error display anyway, you could just make the string into `{{ 'Error'|trans({}, 'messages') }}` or something.